# ¿Como recupero los datos de un Json en kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin

En esta parte registro los datos, pero a la hora de recuperarlos me manda toda la cadena de esta forma
`"no_control":"21120001","nombre":"Alex",
carrera":"ITICs","semestre":7,"contrasenia":"12345"

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        editRegistroNumControl = findViewById(R.id.editRegistroNumControl)
        editRegistroNombre = findViewById(R.id.editRegistroNombre)
        editRegistroCarrera = findViewById(R.id.editRegistroCarrera)
        editRegistroSemestre = findViewById(R.id.editRegistroSemestre)
        editRegistroPass = findViewById(R.id.editRegistroPass)
        btnGuardarRegistro = findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarRegistro)
        btnSalir = findViewById(R.id.btnSalir)

        btnSalir.setOnClickListener { finish() }
//

        val stringBD = intent.getStringExtra("bd")

        var jsonBD = JSONObject(stringBD)

        btnGuardarRegistro.setOnClickListener {
            val json = JSONObject()
            json.put("no_control", editRegistroNumControl.text.toString())

            json.put("nombre", editRegistroNombre.text.toString())

            json.put("carrera", editRegistroCarrera.text.toString())
            json.put("semestre", editRegistroSemestre.text.toString().toInt())
            json.put("contrasenia", editRegistroPass.text.toString())

            val alumnos = jsonBD.getJSONArray("alumnos")
            alumnos.put(json)

            jsonBD = JSONObject()
            jsonBD.put("alumnos", alumnos)

            val intent = Intent(this, Inicio::class.java)

            intent.putExtra("alumno", json.toString())
            intent.putExtra("bd", jsonBD.toString())
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
```

Esta parte es donde recupero la cadena pero quisiera recuperar solo los datos y no las variables.
Por ejemplo de no_control: solo me diera los numeros para ponerlos en un textview.
Estuve buscando informacion pero la verdad soy nuevo en esto, alguien que me ayude porfavor.

```
class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)

        var stringBD = intent.getStringExtra("bd")
        if(stringBD == null) {
            stringBD = resources.getString(R.string.jsonAlumnos)
        }

        val stringAlumno = intent.getStringExtra("alumno")
        textMostrar.text="$stringAlumno"
        /*
        println("Alumno:")
        println(stringAlumno)

        println("BD:")
        println(stringBD)

         */

    }

}
```

Comment: disculpa, olvidaste aceptar la respuesta o no te sirvió?

Answer (score 1):

Es muy mala práctica trabajar directamente con strings, en su lugar deberías crear clases que te sirvan de modelos.
Además no parece que necesites usar json en absoluto. Todo lo que haces es serializar datos para pasarlos de una activity a otra. Eso deberías hacerlo con un parcelable, que es el formato más optimizado en android y es considerablemente más rápido que json.

### Parcelable

Lo primero es agregar el plugin [kotlin-parcelize](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize) en tu archivo build.gradle

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "kotlin-parcelize"
}
```

Luego declaras las clases para almacenar tus datos

```
@Parcelize data class BD(val alumnos: List<Alumno>) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Alumno(
    val carrera: String,
    val contrasenia: String,
    val no_control: String,
    val nombre: String,
    val semestre: Int
) : Parcelable
```

Luego colocas tus datos en instancias de esas clases y como son parcelables puedes agregarlas directamente como extras en tu intent.

```
val BD = intent.getParcelableExtra<BD>("bd")!!
btnGuardarRegistro.setOnClickListener {
    val alumno = Alumno(
        no_control = editRegistroNumControl.text.toString(),
        nombre = editRegistroNombre.text.toString(),
        carrera = editRegistroCarrera.text.toString(),
        semestre = editRegistroSemestre.text.toString().toInt(),
        contrasenia = editRegistroPass.text.toString(),
    )
    val alumnos = BD.copy( BD.alumnos + alumno )
    val intent = Intent(this, Inicio::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("alumno", alumno)
        putExtra("bd", alumnos)
    }
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

Ahora al recibirlo es un objeto de tipo Alumno y como tal puedes acceder a cualquiera de sus propiedades

```
val alumno = intent.getParcelableExtra<Alumno>("alumno")
txtMostrar.text = alumno?.no_control.toString()
```

### Json

En caso de que realmente necesites utilizar json, el procedimiento es muy similar pero en cambio debes usar el plugin [kotlinx-serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html):

```
// build.gradle (Project)
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
}
```

```
// build.gradle (Module)
plugins {
    ...
    id "kotlinx-serialization"
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.0"
}
```

En las clases cambia la anotación y ya no necesitan implementar la interfaz `Parcelable`

```
@Serializable
data class BD(val alumnos: List<Alumno>)    
@Serializable
data class Alumno(...)
```

El resto del código no cambia excepto que debes agregar los métodos `Json.encodeToString` y `Json.decodeFromString` para serializar y deserializar respectivamente tus objetos.

enviar: `putExtra("alumno", Json.encodeToString(alumno))`

recibir: `val alumno = Json.decodeFromString<Alumno>(intent.getStringExtra("alumno")!!)`

De cualquier forma **es demasiado importante que dejes de hardcodear strings** en tu código. De hecho las keys "bd" y "alumno" que pones el los extras deberías reemplazarlas por constantes. De lo contrario tu código se volverá muy difícil de mantener.